# Cart showing minimum order amount error

Tags: cart, magento2.2.2

My cart has a total order amount greater than `$1.00` still it shows an error `Minimum order amount is $1.00`

[image]

As the cart has an order total of `$2.62` even after applying a discount which is greater than the minimum order amount `$1.00` then why this error is being shown?

Any idea?

EDIT: I have debugged it and I found that in file **`vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php`**

```
if (!$minOrderMulti) {
            foreach ($addresses as $address) {
                $taxes = ($taxInclude) ? $address->getBaseTaxAmount() : 0;
                foreach ($address->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
                    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
                    $amount = $item->getBaseRowTotal() - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount() + $taxes;
                    if ($amount < $minAmount) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In above code it considers item's `base row total` in calculation which is `$21.82` in my case and `base_discount_Amount` which is `$21.38` and `tax` is `$0.24` it means it would be **`$21.82 - $21.38+ $0.24 = $0.2`**  which is less than `$1.00`

But why it is taking `base row total` in the calculation instead of `base_price_incl_tax` which is `$24.00` it would work fine then.

Can you please let me know any suggestions on how to overcome this?